# Stripe No such price: a similar object exists in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request

Tags: java, stripe-payments

Within Stripe I'm creating a customer, a session and a subscription.

Create customer :

```
public Customer createCustomer() {
    Stripe.apiKey = key;
    System.out.println("API KEY : " + Stripe.apiKey);
    Customer customer = null;
    CustomerCreateParams params =
              CustomerCreateParams
                .builder()
                .setEmail(this.person.getEmail())
                .setPaymentMethod("pm_card_visa")
                .setInvoiceSettings(
                  CustomerCreateParams.InvoiceSettings
                    .builder()
                    .setDefaultPaymentMethod("pm_card_visa")
                    .build()
                ).build();
            try {
                customer = Customer.create(params);
                person.setStripeId(customer.getId());
                this.personService.update(customer.getId(), person);
                subscribe(customer, createStripSession());                  
                
            }catch (StripeException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
            return customer;    
}
```

Create session :

```
public Session createStripSession() {
    Stripe.apiKey = key;
    System.out.println("API KEY : " + Stripe.apiKey);
    String priceId = "price_1KYX8OCLVCGN5jA7JNtDRaAx";
    
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("limit", 3);
    Session last = null;
    try {
        SessionCollection sessions = Session.list(params);
        List<Session> list = sessions.getData();
        last = list.get(list.size() - 1);
        System.out.println(last.getId());
    }catch (StripeException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
        SessionCreateParams params2 = new SessionCreateParams.Builder()
            .setSuccessUrl("https://example.com/success.html?session_id=" + last.getId())
            .setCancelUrl("https://example.com/canceled.html")
            .setMode(SessionCreateParams.Mode.SUBSCRIPTION)
            .addLineItem(new SessionCreateParams.LineItem.Builder()
    // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
            .setQuantity(1L)
            .setPrice("price_1KYX8OCLVCGN5jA7JNtDRaAx")
            .build()
            )
            .build();
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = Session.create(params2);
    }catch (StripeException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return session;
}
```

create subscription :

```
    public void subscribe(Customer customer, Session session) throws StripeException {
    Stripe.apiKey = key;
    System.out.println("API KEY : " + Stripe.apiKey);
    List<Object> phases = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> item1 = new HashMap<>();
    item1.put(
      "price",
      "price_1KYX8OCLVCGN5jA7JNtDRaAx"
    );
    item1.put("quantity", 1);
    items.add(item1);
    Map<String, Object> phase1 = new HashMap<>();
    phase1.put("items", items);
    phase1.put("iterations", 12);
//   String priceId = request.queryParams("priceId");
    String priceId = "price_1KYX8OCLVCGN5jA7JNtDRaAx";

    SessionCreateParams params = new SessionCreateParams.Builder()
      .setSuccessUrl("https://example.com/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}")
      .setCancelUrl("https://example.com/canceled.html")
      .setMode(SessionCreateParams.Mode.SUBSCRIPTION)
      .addLineItem(new SessionCreateParams.LineItem.Builder()
        // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
        .setQuantity(1L)
        .setPrice(priceId)
        .build()
      )
      .build();

    session = Session.create(params);
    phases.add(phase1);
    Map<String, Object> params2 = new HashMap<>();
    params2.put("customer", customer.getId());
    params2.put("start_date", 1646485214);
    params2.put("end_behavior", "release");
    params2.put("phases", phases);
    SubscriptionSchedule subscriptionSchedule = SubscriptionSchedule.create(params2);
}
```

But when I test my application locally I'm been getting an error :

No such price: 'price_1KYX8OCLVCGN5jA7JNtDRaAx'; a similar object exists in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request.; code: resource_missing; request-id: req_a2cHzmevb7n9pZ

I'm using dashboard in test mode and using the test key but I don't know how to solve this,

Answer (score 1):

The error you mentioned means that the price you are using (`price_1KYX8OCLVCGN5jA7JNtDRaAx`) was created in live mode, so it cannot be used in test mode with your test API keys.

To fix this, you need to create a new price in test mode (either with the API or directly in the Stripe dashboard), and then update the price ID in your code with the new ID.